# Prove $f(x)=1+x^{2/3}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

How to prove that the function $f(x)=1+x^{2/3}$ is continuous?

I begin with

$$|f(x)-f(a)|=|1+x^{2/3}-1-a^{2/3}|=|x^{2/3}-a^{2/3}|$$

From this point on I was unable to proceed, I tried to multiply and divide by $|x^{1/3}+a^{1/3}|$, but I was not able to put in evidence the term $|x-a|$.

Comment: That trick only works with difference of squares. What you want is the conjugate from the difference of cubes formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply and divide by $\left|x^{\frac{4}{3}}+(ax)^{\frac{2}{3}} + a^{\frac{4}{3}}\right|$

$$\left|x^{\frac{2}{3}} - a^{\frac{2}{3}}\right| = \frac{|x^2-a^2|}{\left|x^{\frac{4}{3}}+(ax)^{\frac{2}{3}} + a^{\frac{4}{3}}\right|} = \frac{|x+a||x-a|}{\left|x^{\frac{4}{3}}+(ax)^{\frac{2}{3}} + a^{\frac{4}{3}}\right|}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you!